# Search for an IP with port pattern

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

We're having some issues with our parser right now. We save all of our logs as they are, without parsing.
I need to search over all of our daily logs, and find how many times we get an IP address with port.
for example: `123.123.123.231:45771`

The problem is that the number of digits is different from one request to another (in the IP address and port number).

How should I write my query so I would be able to filter it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would using a Regular Expression (RegEx) to find IP addresses. Take a look at these examples:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html
- https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html

Haven't myself used Google Bigquery, I would encourage taking a look at this question [BigQuery REGEXP_MATCH and accents : boundary wildcard fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160406/bigquery-regexp-match-and-accents-boundary-wildcard-fails) for some more help.

Answer (score 2):

check this out... i included a validity check of the IP itself

```
SELECT Regexp_extract(TXT,r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)') as IP,
Regexp_extract(TXT,r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\:(\d+)') as Port,
Regexp_Match(TXT,r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\:\d+)') as IP_ContainsPort,
Parse_IP(Regexp_extract(TXT,r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)')) as IsValidIP,
if(Parse_IP(Regexp_extract(TXT,r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)')) is null,string(null), Regexp_extract(TXT,r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\:(\d+)')) as PortOfValidIP
FROM 

(Select "123.123.123.231:45771" as TXT),
(Select "1.1.1.1" as TXT),
(Select "23.0.0.1:45" as TXT),
(Select "456.456.456.456:45771" as TXT),
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this pattern

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(:[0-9]{1,4})?$
```